# How to strip characters out of Temp Table after Bulk Insert

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to remove some very annoying inline characters from my .csv file. I need to strip out ! CR LF  because these are junking up my import. I have a proc to try to get rid of the crap but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Cleanup
(
    SimpleData nvarchar(MAX)
)
BULK INSERT #Cleanup from '**********************\myimport.csv' 
SELECT * FROM #Cleanup

DECLARE @ReplVar nvarchar(MAX)
SET @ReplVar = CONCAT(char(33),char(10),char(13),char(32))
UPDATE #Cleanup SET SimpleData = replace([SimpleData], @ReplVar,'') from #Cleanup

SELECT * FROM #Cleanup
```

My plan is if the goofy line break gets removed, the second select should not have it in there. The text looks like

```
js5t,1599,This is this and that is t!
hat,asdf,15426
```

when that line should read

```
js5t,1599,This is this and that is that,asdf,15426
```

### See my quandary? Once the sequential characters ***!crlfsp*** are removed, I will take that temp table and feed it into the working one.

Edit to show varbinary data:

`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

`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

Comment: Perhaps you have the char(10) and char(13) out of order inside your @ReplVar string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@seagulledge, in a comment on the question, is correct, or at least partially correct, in stating that the `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)` are out of order. A carriage-return (CR) is `CHAR(13)` and a line-feed (LF) is `CHAR(10)`.

**HOWEVER,** the main thing preventing this from working is not the order of those two characters: it is the simple fact that the newlines -- whether they are `\r\n` or just `\n` -- are in the *incoming CSV file*, and hence the `BULK INSERT` command is assuming that the newlines are separating input rows (which makes sense for it to do). This can be seen looking at the `VARBINARY` output in the question. There are two rows of output, both starting with `0x`.

This problem can only be solved by fixing the incoming CSV file *prior to* calling `BULK INSERT`. That way the erroneously embedded newlines will be removed such that each row imports as a single row into the temp table.

Comment: The nested replace is a neat trick, but I don't think he wants to remove ALL spaces and exclamation points from the text.

Comment: @seagulledge Ahhh...I see now...I looked at it and the example data a few times and somehow it just didn't click...but now I see it...yes, I will fix my answer...thanks for pointing that out!!

Comment: @seagulledge I fixed it. I re-read your comment as well and you are correct, at least about those two being swapped if you want CRLF. I added a second UPDATE to handle cases were incoming data used just LF for the newline.

Comment: Crap, both ways give me this result:

SharePoint Foundation 2013 Gold and SP1, and SharePoint Server 2013 Gold and SP1 allows remo!
 te attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted Office document, aka ""Microsoft Office Component Use After Free Vulnerability."""

Comment: To test it, I used this to show the before and after:

 SELECT * FROM #Cleanup
 DECLARE ReplVar nvarchar(MAX)
 SET ReplVar = CONCAT(CHAR(33), CHAR(10), CHAR(32));
 UPDATE tmp
 SET    tmp.SimpleData = REPLACE(tmp.[SimpleData], ReplVar, '')
 FROM   #Cleanup tmp;
 SELECT * FROM #Cleanup

Comment: Mind you, the ReplVar is actually @ReplVar, forum squawked at me for having it more than once, something about only one user may be notified...

Comment: @bbcompent1 You might be mistaken about the actual data there. Do a `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), tmp.[SimpleData]) FROM #Cleanup tmp;` and update the question to include the result. Then we can see exactly what characters are adjust `@ReplVar` accordingly. Also, you can enclose code in backwards single-quote (under the tilde) in comments and then the `@` won't be be parsed as referring to a user. Plus, it will make the comment more readable :-).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124554/discussion-between-bbcompent1-and-srutzky).

Comment: Chat doesn't work from behind my corp firewall. You can always send me a PM :)

Comment: @bbcompent1 For the moment, all I really said was that I figured it out and updated my answer accordingly. Please review the update and let me know if you have additional questions.